# передача из C# в SQL-запрос в качестве параметра строки вида N'AAA', N'AAB', N'AAC'

Tags: c#, sql-server

есть хранимая процедура, куда пользователь должен передать фильтр выборки в качестве параметра. фильтр вида
**N'AAA', N'AAB', N'AAC'**.
где каждый элемент - значение в кириллице.
на форме кнопка, при нажатии на которую введенные пользователем через запятую значения преобразуются в строку "N'AAA', N'AAB', N'AAC'"
процедура запускается и ничего не возвращает
в каком виде должен быть передан фильтр в хранимую процедуру?

да, можно загрузить элементы фильтра в таблицу и поставить условие In
но работать будет ОЧЕНЬ медленно

заранее спасибо

Comment: `N` - это префикс для задания литералов [nchar и nvarchar](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Очевидно, вам нужно просто убрать его и использовать "AAA" и т. п. Покажите C# код, как именно вы задаёте значения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите вашу хранимую процедуру в SQL Server. Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Answer (score 0):

после долгих поисков было принято следующее решение: весь текст хранимой процедуры вместе со списком фильтров (в цикле) преобразовывается в строку и эта строка исполняется (sqlcommand1.ExecuteReader()). скорость обработки запроса упала с 20 минут до 50 сек. выгружает 100,000  записей.

Comment: Вы задали вопрос про строки вида `N'AAA'`. А ответили на что-то совсем другое.

Comment: ранее было сказано: N - это префикс для задания литералов nchar и nvarchar. Очевидно, вам нужно просто убрать его и использовать "AAA" и т. п. задача (пусть и не очевидная): БЫСТРАЯ обработка запроса. загрузка отбираемых значений в таблицу замедляет обработку. поэтому скрипт вместе с фильтрами преобразуется в строку и далее старая добрая классика VS2005: SqlString=...  SqlComm=new SqlCommand (SqlString,ConnSrv); SqlDataReader MyDr=SqlComm.ExecureReader()